# Python regex get value between two words from multiple line

Tags: python, regex, file

Below is the file in which I am trying to get all the values and all the occurrences  between **Data** and **Column**

**Current Code**

```
import re

filedata = open('test.csv', 'r')

re.findall(r'data\n+(.*)', filedata.read(), re.I)
```

**Current Output**

```
output = ['1,test', '10,test', '100,test']
```

**Expected Output from below file**

```
output = ['1,test', '2,test', '10,test', '11,test', '100,test', '200,test]
```

**test.csv**

```
Column
Num,Tape
data

1,test
2,test

column
Num,Tape
Data

10,test
20,test

column
Num,Tape
Data
100,test
200,test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

filedata = open('test.csv', 'r')

re.findall(r'^((?!column|data|Num|Tape).+)+$', filedata.read(), re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: data is not fixed, in place of test there can be anything. Also I need everything between Data and Column

Comment: @akshay-sharma  fixed code. check now. gives output like ['1,test', '2,test', '10,test', '20,test', '100,test', '200,test']

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```py
import re

filedata = open('test.csv', 'r')

re.findall(r'\d+.+', filedata.read(), re.I)
```